# How to resolve "Error copying file or folder"?

Tags: windows-networking

There are two machines in LAN. Machine A & Machine B.

On machine A, folder A is shared. I am copying that shared folder A from machine A to machine B. After copying few files, I got following error.

> Error Copying File or Folder
>   Cannot copy clAccess: Access is denied.
>   Make sure the disk is not full or write-protected and that the file is not currently in use.

Machine A is in ideal position, no one application is using file `clAccess`.

Then how can we resolve this issue?

Comment: Transfer your question to superuser.com

Comment: What programming language/environment? How are you copying the files, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have write permissions on the destination folder.
If you can, get ownership of the destination folder, and grant yourself write permission.